# Turing machine that accept L = {ww} in linearithmic time

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, turing-machines

I was wondering if there is a way to design a deterministic turing machine that accept the language L = {ww} with a time complexity of O(n log(n))

Comment: For a Turing machine that low a complexity for doing _anything_ nontrivial seems overly optimistic.

Comment: Over the alphabet $\Sigma = \{v,w\}$ I could do it :)

Comment: Could you provide an example please ?